# Find right index of checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, checkbox

I am trying to combine form results. So if a checkbox is checked I want to save the ID of the checkbox combined with the value of the select box in the same row. I do this by looping through the checkbox $_POST array and use the index to find the right result of the selectbox $_POST array.

The problem is is that if I for example check the second checkbox and the first not, the index of the checkbox array is '0' (1 item) and the index of the selectbox array is '1' (2 items). With the result that I get the first selectbox, which is the wrong one:

```
$_POST['selectbox'][0]
```

How can I get the right index?

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="10">
            <select name="selectbox[]">
                <option value="value_1">Value 1</option>
                <option value="value_2">Value 2</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="11">
            <select name="selectbox[]">
                <option value="value_1">Value 1</option>
                <option value="value_2">Value 2</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if( ! empty( $_POST['checkbox'] ) ) {
    $examples = array();
    foreach( $_POST['checkbox'] as $index => $value ) {
        $examples[] = array(
            'checkbox'  => $value,
            'selectbox' => $_POST['selectbox'][$index]
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you add the index inside the brackets? ^^ `checkbox[1]` as far as I remember its just for grouping, you can even add normal names.

Comment: add an index to the html: `checkbox[0]`, `selectbox[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might draw the right attention to just put my answer in an actual answer:

Just give your html-element a name:

```
... name="checkbox[index_or_name]" >
```

The first part will be for the grouping, and the identifier between the brackets is just.. well an identifier. Else they just stack up, plus its good practice to know which element you refer to in your php-code.

Comment: Yeah was quite a search to me to once I had to deal with it. Eventually it was quit helpful in a big search form. Since I could easily divide my checkbox groups xD handy feature of PHP